# Assigning points based on data from sql query

Tags: sql, db2-400

Is there a way within sql (db2) to assign points based on values of columns, i.e. for every 5 sales you get one point and for every 100 dollars you get one point?

My query:

```
SELECT SALES, DOLLARS, EMPLOYEE FROM EMP_SALES;
```

I'd like to add a 'POINTS' column where the value is a combination of points from the sales/dollars columns like above. So if the user made 5 sales totaling over 100 dollars, they would have 2 points.

Is there a good way to do this in sql or should I just do this via PHP?

With this table:

```
EMPLOYEE  |  SALES  |  DOLLARS
-------------------------------
123          5            100
456          5            500
```

I would desire these results:

```
EMPLOYEE  |  SALES  |  DOLLARS  |  POINTS
-------------------------------------------
123          5            100        2   
456          5            5          6
```

Comment: you should include example data and the expected results..

Comment: @Charles you're right, I added in an example now

Comment: what is the formula you are looking for to convert sales/dollars to points?  The example is not clear how you are awarding points.

Comment: I'll take even a simple example and fit it, but in this example I was stating that 5 sales = 1 point and 100 dollars = 1 point

Answer (score 1):

Seems like simple arithmetic (assuming the dollars = 5 for employee 456 is a typo and it should be 500)

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE, SALES, DOLLARS
       , (sales/5) + floor(dollars/100) as points 
FROM EMP_SALES
```

note that the [floor()](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=functions-floor) function

> returns the largest integer value less than or equal to expression.

In other words it always rounds down.  You could also use the round() function, but the expression wouldn't be as straight-forward.

Comment: Doesn't DB2 perform integer division? I.e. can't you skip floor?

Comment: Sure, if you're using integers, but I assume dollars at least has a decimal value...